# Can I have a REST element URI without a collection URI?

Tags: rest

a basic REST question.. I design a REST API and would like to be able to get a list of book recommendations based on a book id (i.e. client sends book id=w to server and server replies with a list of recommended books, id=x,y,z).

I see two ways to do this:

1. `/recommendation?bookId=thetitle`
2. `/recommendation/thetitle`

Option 2 seems a bit cleaner to me but I'm not sure if it would be considered good REST design? Because `/recommendation/thetitle` looks like an element URI, not a collection URI (although in this case it would return a collection). Also, the first part of the resource (`/recommendation`) would not make any sense by itself.

Thankful for any advice.

Comment: *Option 2 seems a bit cleaner to me but I'm not sure if it would be considered good REST design?* nope.

Answer (score 2):

URL patterns of this kind have nothing to do with REST. None of the defining properties of REST requires readable URLs.

At the same time, one of the core principles (HATEOAS), if followed properly, allows API clients (applications, not people!) to browse the API and obtain every link required to perform a desired transition of application state or resource state based on a well known message format.

If you feel your API must have readable URLs, it's a good sign that its design probably isn't RESTful at all. This implies the need for a developer to understand the URL structure and hardcode it somewhere in a client application. Something that REST is supposed to avoid by principle.

To quote Roy Fielding's [blog post on the subject](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven):

> A REST API **must not define fixed resource names or hierarchies** (an obvious coupling of client and server). Servers must have the freedom to control their own namespace. Instead, allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such as is done in HTML forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within media types and link relations. [Failure here implies that clients are assuming a resource structure due to out-of band information, such as a domain-specific standard, which is the data-oriented equivalent to RPC’s functional coupling].

Obviously, nothing stops you from actually making URLs meaningful regardless of how RESTful your API actually is. Even if it's for a purpose  not dictated by REST itself (viewing the logs left by a client of a properly RESTful API could be easier for a human if they're readable, off the top of my head).

Finally, if you're fine with developing a Web API that's not completely RESTful and you expect developers of clients to read this kind of docs and care about path building, you might actually benefit from comprehensible URLs. This can be very useful in APIs of the so-called *levels 0-3*, according to [Richardson's maturity model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

What's important in terms of REST is how you're leveraging the underlying protocol (HTTP in this case) and what it allows you to do. If we consider your examples from this perspective, `/recommendation/thetitle` seems preferable. This is because the use of query parameters may prevent responses from being cached by browsers (important if you're writing a JS client) or proxies, making it harder to reuse existing tools and infrastructure.